# I am trying to edit cells in a table and my table is nxn matrix with similar values on either sides of the diagonal

Tags: javascript, angular, matrix, angular-reactive-forms

Using angular reactive forms, I am generating nxn matrix tables based on the number of checkboxes selected. But I want to edit the table cells with same values on either sides which can be done using 2-way binding on opposite cells. and all diagonal values are 1 non editable.

Code so far.

```
  <div class="form-group">
       <table *ngIf="showTable" class="table table-striped table-bordered" 
          style="width:50%;" formControlName="correlations">
            <thead>
                 <tr>
                      <th *ngFor="let parameter of checked">{{parameter}}</th>
                 </tr>
             </thead>
             <tbody>
                  <tr *ngFor="let row of correlationValues">
                       <td contenteditable="true" style="background-
                           color:#b1dbf9" *ngFor="let col of row">{{col}}</td>
                  </tr>
             </tbody>
       </table>
   </div>
```

The column values are coming from the selected checkbox values.

Code for creating matrix.

```
createMatrix(n:number) {
    var innerArr;
   this.correlationValues = [];

    for (var i=0; i<n; i++){
        innerArr = [];
        for (var j=0; j<n; j++) {
            innerArr.push((i+j+1)%2);
        }
        this.correlationValues.push(innerArr);
    }
    console.log(this.correlationValues.toString());
    return this.correlationValues;
}
```

I want to edit table cell values using angular reactive forms.

Comment: The angular-way to solve such problem, use jquery